# Lisp scope issue with setq?

Tags: scope, lisp

I'm a noob at lisp, have only been using it for two weeks or so...

I have some global variable declared with setq:
`(setq myvar '(WHATEVER))`

and a function that is supposed to modify whatever variable I tell it to:

```
(defun MYFUN (varname)
  (setq varname '(POOP))
)
```

but when I make the call: `(MYFUN 'myvar)`
and check the value of `myvar` now it still is `(WHATEVER)` how do I make the changes that are made in `MYFUN` persist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the value of the local variable `varname`, not the global variable whose name it contains. To do what you want you need to use the `symbol-value` accessor to indirect through it to get the global value's variable.

```
(defun myfun (varname) 
  (setf (symbol-value varname) '(poop)))
```

Comment: @user2934041 Or rename local variable to remove the name clash. Or better, rename global variable to more stylistically correct `*myvar*`.

Comment: The name clash is irrelevant. `(setq argumentvar something)` always sets the local variable, it never indirects through it.

Comment: @mobiuseng As he says in the question, he wants the function to modify whatever he passes as the argument. He doesn't want to hard-code the name of the global variable into the function.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the intention: so he wants to pass the symbol as an argument and modify the variable "named" by that symbol? OK, got it. But will only work for global variables (and not for locals in enclosed environment).

Comment: Of course. The first thing he said is he has a global variable he wants to change. He calls the function like `(myfun 'myvar)`

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as "declaring a global variable with setq", there is only "set the value of a variable with setq" and if you're doing that in the top lexical environment, the results are amusingly under-defined.

If you look at what the variable `varname` contains, it may well be the list `(poop)`.

Also, the "q" at the end of `setq` actually means "quoted" (that is, the `setq` special form will not evaluate the first (and third, and fifth...) argument, but will do so for the second (and fourth, and sixth...).

It was, historically, used as a convenience, where `(set (quote var) value)` was less convenient than `(setq var value)`. However, `(set var value)` has exactly the same effect as `(setf (symbol-value var) value)` and you should use that.

Comment: I don't have a problem reading `(set var value)` but I avoid writing it because [set is deprecated](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set.htm#set). The difference between `set` and `setq` is more than just adding a `q` and removing a quote: for people learning CL, the difference between symbol's value cells and bindings can be confusing at first and from that point of view, `symbol-value` is a little more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: didn't notice this first:

You have local `varname` and global `varname` both in the scope of the function body. Local name shadows the global name. So, if you change the local name to `var` it should work the way you wrote (checked in SBCL 1.2.13). But consider the following stylistic corrections:

1. For global variables, please use ear-muffs `*` around the name, so it should be `*myvar*`. Global variables are *special* (there is a way to make them normal, but it is not necessarily a good idea). Special variables have *dynamic* scope, in contrast to *lexical* scope of normal variables.
2. The variable must be declared with `defvar` or `defparameter`. You can use `setq` for this but the compiler is going to complain that the variable is not defined. Also, with `setq` the variable is not going to be special.
3. For a variable `*myvar*` to appear special inside the body of the function, it either needs to be declared (with `defvar` or `defparameter`) before function definition, or it needs to be declared special in the body of the function with `(declare (special *myvar*))` and then declared with `defvar` or `defparameter`.

Here is the code of possible combinations of declarations and respective outputs:

```
;; This is a model solution:
(defvar *myvar* 'a)
*MYVAR*

(defun foo (var)
  (setq *myvar* var))

(foo 'b)
*myvar*
B

;; Not using DEFVAR or DEFPARAMETER
(setq myvar 'a)
A

(defun bar (var)
  (setq myvar var))
;; The value of the global MYVAR is still changed
(bar 'b)
myvar
B
(defun show-myvar ()
  myvar)
;; But MYVAR is not special
(let ((myvar 'z))
  (show-myvar))
B

;; Also can assign value to undeclared variable
(defun bar2 (var)
  (setq myvar-1 var))
BAR2

(setq myvar-1 'a)
A
;; And it works
(bar2 'b)
myvar-1
B

;; Finally: show special undeclared (yet) variable
(defun show-special ()
  (declare (special *special-var*))
  *special-var*)

(defvar *special-var* 'a)
*SPECIAL-VAR*

(let ((*special-var* 'z))
  (show-special))
Z

;; The same but with SETQ: variable is still not special
(defun show-special-setq ()
  (declare (special *special-var-setq*))
  *special-var-setq*)

(setq *special-var-setq* 'a)
A
(let ((*special-var-setq* 'z))
  (show-special-setq))
A
```